# Connection reset by peer on my Mac whenever downloading large files from Microsoft

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, download

This is very strange, when downloading large files from virtually all Microsoft websites I get a 'The operation couldn't be completed. Connection reset by peer' error.

For example, I'm just trying to download the update for Office 2011 but have this problem. It downloads about 2.6MB before hitting this error.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed Lion and this issue seems to have gone away now. All fixed - strange :S